# Comments feed - Undefined named entity: ndash

Tags: comments, feed

I used to have a rss comment feed at the url /comments/feed which doesn't work anymore.

I checked the feed [on feedvalidator](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http://mart-e.be/comments/feed/) and I've an error

> line 111, column 29: Undefined named entity: ndash [help]

The line in question is comment where the content is

```
<guid isPermaLink="false">http://mart-e.be/?p=1694#comment-9711</guid>
<description>Ou mettre des &ndash; à la place des -
Mais oui la solution de rcommande fonctionne bien :)</description>
```

In the context, it is normal that there was an `&ndash;` there (explaining to write `--` with `&ndash;&ndash;`).

Any idea how to fix this feed error ?

Comment: `/comments/feed/`still works on 3.3. Please provide more information for us to be able to investigate further. As it stands now the only way this can be answered is if someone has had the exact same problem and managed to solve it.

Comment: Ok actually the feed is working but invalid. I've updated the post content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue may be the same over here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17767

Its currently submitted as a bug and hasn't been fixed yet. You can give the supplied attachment a go to see if it fixes the issue for you.

```
<description>Ou mettre des &ndash; à la place des -
Mais oui la solution de rcommande fonctionne bien :)</description>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>Ou mettre des &amp;ndash; à la place des -<br />
Mais oui la solution de rcommande fonctionne bien <img src='http://mart-e.be/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_smile.gif' alt=':)' class='wp-smiley' /> </p>
]]></content:encoded>
```

You can see in your feed that the `&ndash;` is properly encoded in content but not the description.

Quick fix is to delete the comment with the `&ndash;` in it.

Comment: Thanks applying the [patch](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/17767/comments-cdata-suggestion.diff) worked for me!